How do I empty the Kernel Keyring Buffer withouta restart?
I'm planning on using the Ext4 file encryption ability. Everything works fine, but there is one problem left. After removing the PASSWORD via keyctl, i still can see the content of the encrypted directory. I tried deleting the key, syncing and emptying the page cache, unmount the filesystem, restart the caja file manager and mounting the fs, again. But it doesn't work. Although i can't write to the directory anymore, i still can see clear names.
How do I empty the Kernel's KeyRing Cache? (without rebooting or restarting my X session)
Sources:

Introduction
Tutorial
e4crypt - man page
Login implementation
Linux Kernel Keyring - notes


Have you tried echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop-caches to drop the dcache?

This seems to work. Although it didn't one time of all times i tried. Is there any way to achieve this without unmounting? I have docker running on that disk. Else poste it as answer and i will accept it.

You can use echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop-caches to drop the dcache from all filesystems on the system. That isn't ideal, since it also drops cache on other filesystems.
I don't think there is a mechanism to flush the icache/dcache on a per-filesystem basis.
